# What tool is able to find and extract loops from a video?

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

I'd like to have a tool, that finds loops in a video and is able to extract them. As a `mp4`, `webm` or `gif` is fine.

[loopFindr](https://github.com/cyburgee/loopFindr) seems to be able to do exactly that, but apparently it's only available for MacOS.

Is there any equivalent available for Windows?

Preferably it can also create perfect loops from *not-perfectly-looped-videos*.

Answer (score 1):

[Automated video looping with progressive dynamism](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52024&from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownloads%2Fd02f3198-7896-45eb-89e8-5a75859b67c8%2F)

Via this [2013 SIGGRAPH presentation](https://youtu.be/drKmS-Czu44)

Comment: Can you describe the features of the proposed software and how does it complies with the OP's request?